# Nothing appears on screen in OpenGL (GLFW/GLEW)

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

Recently, I have been transitioning from LWJGL (which I am experienced with) to C++'s OpenGL API.  I fallowed [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/) since I could not get my vbo classes to work correctly.  The code is below:

```
#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

GLFWwindow* window;

void init()
{

}

static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] =
{
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};

void render()
{
    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

static void errorCallback(int error, const char* desc)
{
    fputs(desc, stderr);
}

static void keyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scanCode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

void initWindow()
{
    glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello, world!", NULL, NULL);

    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);

    glewExperimental = true;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void destroyWindow()
{
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(int argCount, char **args)
{
    initWindow();
    init();
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
        render();
    destroyWindow();
}
```

I have read through it over and over and looked around the internet.  However, other posts I've read are clearer mistakes.  I am probably making a really obvious mistake here, and I know how inefficient the fact that I create a buffer every frame is, however that is just to test and see if I can get it to work.  I would appreciate if somebody could tell me what I am doing wrong here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an OpenGL 3.3 core profile. In such a context, the use of [Vertex Array Objects (VAO)](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) is *mandatory*. The same is true for program objects. You have to specify your own [shaders](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader) and cannot make use of the fixed function pipleline. The `glLoadIdentity` call refers to the deprecated matrix stack functionality which is also removed in core profiles.

Your `glDrawArrays` call should generate a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` because you have no program object and no VAO bound at the time of the draw call. I generally recommend to add GL error checks at least for debug builds. If the GL version you are targeting supports it, I recommend using a [debug context](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Debug_Output) instead. It will make spotting errors during development much easier.

Also note that none of these issues a related to the switch from java with LWJGL to C++. If you used a legacy context /  core profile with java before, you could also do so in C++ (although I strongly advise you to learn modern GL instead), and you would have seen the same issues if you used a modern core profile context with LWJGL.

Comment: Just to clarify: This is working code, and even though it uses vertex arrays it is still a VBO? [Link to Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/fBw007D0)

Comment: @ZachGoethel: That question doesn't make sense. Apparently, this is _not_ working code, and the answer explains why. The " even though it uses vertex arrays it is still a VBO?" part is totally beyond me. VBOs are VBOs because they _store_ vertex arrays. Don't confuse vertex arrays with vertex array objects. The latter only store meta information, while the VBOs store the actual vertex arrays.

Comment: "This code" refers to the link I gave.  And by "Is it a VBO" I meant to ask if the data is still stored on the GPU or if it is sent every frame.

Comment: As part of another question, I renamed my class to MeshRenderer since it should not be referred to as a VBO.

Comment: The link you gave does not contain any VBO-related code. It just demonstrates creating a window with a GL context. You seem to be stack at the _middle_ of the following tutorial, which explicitely states "If you’re on lucky, you can see the result (**don’t panic if you don’t**)". However, you skipped the VAO part at the beggining of that tutorial 2, so you won't see anything even if you add the shaders later. I don't really like that tutorial, but if you follow _all_ of the steps to the end of the second tutorial, it should be working.

Comment: The link in my comment.  The one that says "Link to Pastebin" and leads to http://pastebin.com/fBw007D0